# How to fix stalled archival process with ServicePulse?

Tags: nservicebus

In my environment I am running ServicePulse v1.14.4 and ServiceControl v3.3.0.  I periodically go in to check for error messages and they're are in excess of 280K.  So I start the archive process and hope they get archived.  After 4 days the process is still going or seems to be hung up at 66%.

My question is there any way to get this back on track without having to restart the services?